# multiple playlists MP3 Flash Player

Tags: mp3, flash, playlist

I would like to play a certain song depending sent parameter.

In my project I have different playlist, so i want to send the parameter(which is a number, corresponding to a just one playlist) and then just listen the song in that playlist.Any idea about how can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as I read on the flash webpage unfortunately this feature is not implemented.
That's why I'm using jQuery jPlayer now